# Error on writing file - it is used by other process

Tags: c#, file, io

I tired to write in loop virus signatures to files. 
My code :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < liczba; i++)
                {
                    int current = i + 1;
                    string xxx = w.DownloadString("xxx(hidden)");
                    if (xxx != "0")
                    {
                        string[] wirus = xxx.Split("|||".ToCharArray());
                        string s2 = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "_RDTSignatures", "base000" + current.ToString() + ".rdtsignature");
                        File.Create(s2);
                        StreamWriter sss = new StreamWriter(s2); //that's crash line
                        sss.WriteLine("hidden");
                        sss.WriteLine(wirus[0]);
                        sss.WriteLine(wirus[1]);
                        sss.Close();
                        File.Encrypt(s2);
                    }
                }
```

`w` is a `WebClient` object. Error callback :

```
System.IO.IOException: Process cannot access file : „C:\Users\Pluse Konto\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Radzik Diagnostic Tool\Radzik Diagnostic Tool\bin\Debug\_RDTSignatures\base0001.rdtsignature”, because it is used by other process.
   w System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   w System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   w System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   w System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   w System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   w System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path)
   w Radzik_Diagnostic_Tool.Updates.timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) w C:\Users\Pluse Konto\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Radzik Diagnostic Tool\Radzik Diagnostic Tool\Updates.cs:line 69
   w System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   w System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   w System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I don't know what is the reason of that error. No process is using my files, except my main thread, of course.

PS File `base0001.rdtsignature` has been created, but is empty.

Comment: I am assuming the error occurs on your second iteration in the loop. The problem is that you are not disposing (and thus not closing the file) the file created on the line `File.Create(s2);` which you repeatedly try to create in your loop.

Comment: @Alex Not second iteration first iteration itself will fail. `File.Create(s2)` returns open `FileStream`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you are right. I had not even noticed it tries to open/create the same file on both those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't close the file created by `File.Create(s2);`.

Try `using( File.Create(s2) );` or `File.Create(s2).Close();`

Comment: This will work, but calling File.Create is not necessary as the line directly after it will create the file for you.

Comment: @FrankRundatz Of course, there are many ways to do it. I just pointed out the bug.

Answer (score 2):

`File.Create` returns the open `FileStream`, So when you create new `StreamWriter` it tries to access the file which is already opened in your process with `File.Create` results in `IOException`

Try this

```
using (StreamWriter sss = new StreamWriter(File.Create(s2)))
{
    //Make use of sss
}
```

Using statement ensures underlying stream of `StreamWriter` is closed when control exits `Using`. So no need to call  `sss.Close();` manually. using statement does it for you even when there is exception thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Just comment out:

File.Create(s2);

The problem is that File.Create(s2) returns a FileStream which leaves the file open.  You are then trying to create a second stream to open the file for writing again which is why you get the error that the file is already open.

If you always want to create a new file, change your line that creates the StreamWriter to read:

StreamWriter sss = new StreamWriter(s2, false);

That will make it not append to an existing file but rather overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
File.Create(s2);
StreamWriter sss = new StreamWriter(s2); //that's crash line
```

Use:

```
StreamWriter sss = File.CreateText(s2);
```